# 18.04 upgrade - HP 8720 MFP - scanner permissions

Tags: usb, permissions, 18.04, scanner

I have upgraded to 18.04.  Everything works except the scanner.
sane-find-scanner finds the USB scanner.

Device response is "could not open USB device xxx/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions

I have followed old postings and have checked permissions.
Command results
sudo adduser saned scanner
The user `saned' is already a member of`scanner'.
$ sudo adduser saned lp
  The scanner is part of the lp and scan group.

HP Device Manager cannot find the scanner. SANE, Simple scan etc cannot find the scanner.

The other postings on this do not address permissions so I have added this as a new post.

Any thoughts on resolution?  Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: if you type `hp-check` in a terminal, that checks you have the files installed that are needed; if you then type `hp-setup` it should attempt to set up the scanner for you; I wonder if it succeeds

Answer (score 0):

The group of USB device is now `lp`.

It is necessary for the user to be in group `lp`.

You can use de command:

```
sudo adduser <username> lp
```

If you are in X sessión you need to logout and login again.

Confirm you have the `lp` group with the command `id`.